# Ignore specific delimiter scenary on Python CSV read

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file like:

```
Time,Value1,Value2
246.58124,X,X
246.581245,h2C[,],X
246.58125,X,h2C[,]
246.581255,X,h2C[,]
246.58126,X,h2C[,]
```

`h2C[,]` stands for a code (unique value). How to ignore the column separator `,` if it is `[,]` in Python? I am using `csv.DictReader(foo)`.

Comment: This is why I recommend using tab-separated files `sep='\t'` for reading and writing. Simply sidesteps this issue. I recommend using Pandas, by the way.

Comment: @AdrianKeister but what if there are tabs in the data?

Comment: That's not common in my experience. I suppose it can happen. You want to use, as a delimiter, something that does NOT occur inside a field. Sounds like you need more control over your data generation process.

Comment: This is a good question, but I suspect you won't find a great answer to it. One good idea is to use some character to quote your data in the csv (a regular quote `"` works if you don't have it in your data) because csv reader can handle quotes. Another is to use a distinct delimiter that does not occur in your data. But these are hindsight solutions.

Comment: I also prefer '\t' to write my "CSVs". But this is exported by an other software. Maybe defining the `quotechar` param of `DictReader` initialization?

Comment: I think "quotechar" might work (though you'll need to preprocess and quote all "problematic" values first anyway)

Comment: @hildogjr if you're using '\t' as a delimiter, you're writing tsv files, not csv.

Comment: How to preprocess this problematic value on the code? (iteratively, with read and write the file)

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-parse each line before converting it to a CSV row as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

data = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        data.append(next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(line.replace("[,]", "")))))
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df)
```

Giving you a Pandas dataframe:

```
         Time Value1 Value2
0   246.58124      X      X
1  246.581245    h2C      X
2   246.58125      X    h2C
3  246.581255      X    h2C
4   246.58126      X    h2C
```

The `io.StringIO()` is used to convert `line` into a file like object for the `csv.reader()` to use.