# Ignoring delimiter while reading CSV files from URLs - Python

Tags: pandas, python-requests, read.csv

I have some URLs for downloading CSV files.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

url1 = 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&uri=/economy/economicoutputandproductivity/output/timeseries/' + 'k22a' + '/diop'

url2 = 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&uri=/economy/economicoutputandproductivity/output/timeseries/' + 'k24c' + '/diop'

s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

When I use `url1`, there is a `','` in the 4th record. But some urls (`url2`) dont have this unexpected separator. This is causing

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line
> 5, saw 2

when I try to merge the CSV files into a single dataframe. How do I ignore these unexpected separators. Anyway the first seven records are to be deleted. But I still get this error.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68036832/4399016) suggests we pre-parse each line before converting into CSV. Since I have many such URLs, and don't know for sure which unexpected delimiters would be encountered in future, not sure how to debug. Can pre-parsing before converting to CSV work? How to implement in such a manner to include other separators encountered in the future?

Comment: both urls seem to work without errors for me

Comment: No error now. When we merge a whole bunch of them it causes error.

Comment: It's tricky to automatically handle an invalid format from an external output if you don't know exactly what causes the issue. I'd suggested to have a function to take a URL as input, catch the errors and report to a human when such cases are found. Trying to have some unsupervised magic fix the data might just lead to loading invalid data without you knowing it.

Comment: The first seven lines have to be deleted anyway. Only the floats below are useful. The metadata is causing error here.

Comment: then just skip those with `skiprows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need the metadata, just skip it using the `skiprows` parameter of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). As a nice side effect, you'll also have the correct dtypes automatically:

```
url = url1
N = 7

s = requests.get(url1).content
c = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')), header=0, skiprows=range(1, N+1))
```

Output:

```
  Title  IOP: C:MANUFACTURING: CVMSA
0  1948                         25.2
1  1949                         27.0
2  1950                         29.0
3  1951                         29.9
4  1952                         28.4
...
```

If you don't even need headers:

```
url = url1
N = 8

s = requests.get(url1).content
c = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')), header=None, skiprows=N)
```

Output:

```
      0     1
0  1948  25.2
1  1949  27.0
2  1950  29.0
3  1951  29.9
4  1952  28.4
...
```

Comment: I tried to read into pandas first and then did 'df = df.iloc[7:  ]'.  Still got error while merging. Anyway, let me try this.

Comment: It's much better to avoid reading the rows rather than filtering them. This will avoid having an object dtype since you have strings, and also avoid the issues you had since the headers are not CSV